# Android's Chrome bookmarks won't show up in desktop's Chrome

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, chrome-for-android, bookmarks

I have a Moto G (Kitkat 4.4.2) which I've synced to my Google account. The desktop Chrome bookmarks show up just fine in my cellphone's Chrome but the bookmarks added via the phone, which are stored in a `Cellphone bookmarks` folder in my phone, won't show up in my desktop's Chrome (elementary OS Luna).

I have *Sync everything* enabled in my desktop's Chrome. How can I force Android's Chrome bookmarks to sync with my desktop's chrome?

### **Edit**

I just realized that the `Cellphone bookmark` folder **is** present in my desktop's Chrome but *I can only see it* if I go into the `Bookmarks manager` (or `Manage bookmarks`, translating from Spanish here) option. The folder does show there but it doesn't in the bookmarks bar. This is starting to look like a bug in Chrome. Anyone else can reproduce this?

Answer (score 2):

So, you can bookmark folders in your bookmarks manager. Just hit the star to bookmark your bookmarks manager while viewing your mobile bookmarks and stick it in your bookmarks bar, or where ever you want.

Comment: This is an interesting workaround. I never realize you could bookmark the "Bookmark Manager". Fortunately, when selecting a folder, Chrome append the ID to the URL, making the folder bookmarkable just like you said (albeit, we cannot expand the folder from "Bookmarks Bar" directly).

Answer (score 1):

In your android chrome browser go to Settings. Under settings you'll be able to see your email id in the Basics section (its mostly located right on top). Selecting the email will take you to the Services section. There you will find an option called Sync. Select it. Make sure sync is enabled and the bookmarks section is checked. I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not what I need. In both devices (Android's Chrome and desktop's Chrome) the _Sync_ option is selected with _All_ checked, which includes bookmarks.

Comment: Give this a try http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/google-in-the-enterprise/steps-to-resolve-chrome-bookmark-synchronization-issues/

Comment: That site might be onto something. I checked my https://www.google.com/settings/chrome/sync and it shows 234 bookmarks which is about rigth, but 251 opened tabs (!) which is _definitely_ not right.

Comment: I had the sync enabled, I just disabled it and enabled it back again and it synced my bookmarks.